# How to fix a string length in python

Tags: python, string, format

I have this simple program that reads in a list and capitalizes the first letter but I want to fix the string length to be the same for all strings and then output to a new list, with the new strings in the centre and padded to the left and right - I've seen different ways but haven't got them to work. Could anybody help, please! Thanks!

```py
old_list = ['cow', 'dog', 'elephant', 'horse']
new_list = []

for item in old_list:
    new_list.append(item.capitalize())
    print(item)

for item in new_list:
    print(len(item))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For variable width (longest word limited)

```py
old_list = ['cow', 'dog', 'elephant', 'horse']
max = 0
for i in old_list:
    if len(i) > max:
        max = len(i)

new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    new_list.append('{item:^{width}}'.format(item=i, width=max))
```

```
  cow   
  dog   
elephant
 horse
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this - how would I format the item in the loop when I am reading it in from the old list before appending to the new_list. Something like item.format..thanks for replying

Comment: Replace the print with:
`new_list.append('{item:^{width}}'.format(item=i, width=max))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formatted string to center them with a fixed width

```
for i in new_list:
    print('{:^12s}'.format(i))
```

Output

```
    Cow     
    Dog     
  Elephant  
   Horse
```

In this example, all strings are set to 12 characters wide and are centered.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this - how would I format the item in the loop when I am reading it in from the old list before appending to the new_list. Something like item.format..thanks for replying

Comment: I wasn't being clear the part I was struggling with was adding the new formatted items to a new list